# Sql not updating elements in proper order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an animals table and am trying to update the type of all dogs to be cats, and then make the existing cats to be dogs.

So far I have

```
UPDATE Animals
SET name='Cat' 
WHERE name = 'Dog' 
   SET name = 'Dog'
   WHERE name = 'Cat';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle both scenarios in one query:

```
UPDATE Animals SET name = (CASE WHEN name = 'Dog' THEN 'Cat' ELSE 'Dog' END)
   WHERE name IN ('Cat', 'Dog');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try three queries:

```
UPDATE Animals SET name = 'Animal' WHERE name='Dog';
UPDATE Animals SET name = 'Dog' WHERE name='Cat';
UPDATE Animals SET name = 'Cat' WHERE name='Animal';
```